# What am I missing when i try to add to a database through Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn Java Spring Boot and Hibernate, and have checked example after example, but when I'm trying to do it myself I only get NullPointerExceptions when I run my methods. I'm new to this and do not understand everything yet, but I can not see what differs my code from the other examples. Sure, I do not initialize the Autowired objects, but they are never initialized in the examples I have seen either. As I understood it, it is something the autowiring does. Probably it is something about the autowiring I don't understand. Please help me!

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity listUsers() {
            List users = userService.list();
            return new ResponseEntity(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity findById(@PathVariable(name = "id", value = "id") String name) {
            Optional<User> user = userService.findById(name);
            return new ResponseEntity(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody User user) {
            userService.save(user);
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Service
public class UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> list() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<User> findById(String name) {
        return userRepository.findById(name);
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String>{

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name") })
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public User(String name, String password) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: WHERE exactly do you get your nullopointerexception?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you are getting null pointer exception but @Id annotation expect Long or Integer by default

Comment: Can you try userService.findByName(name) instead of userService.findById(name) and check if it works.

Comment: The NullPointerException occurs with userService.save(user) in UserController, but I found the eror: I hadn't AutoWired the UserController object which I called the method with. Anyway, but thanks for your help!